# Matlab: Graphing Reverse Fibonacci

Tags: matlab, plot

I have made a short code that that starts at a value (in my case, one million) and then completes a reverse-Fibonacci by minusing the previous two digits until we get as close to zero as possible. We then log how many steps it took to get to the lowest digit.

For example, we start at 1,000,000 and then loop through a bunch of numbers as the second digit. Let's say we use the digit 5.
1,000,000 - 5 = 999,995
5 - 999,995 = -999,990

-999,990 is less than zero, so we would log the number 2 (the two numbers being 1,000,000 and 5)

Now we loop through a whole bunch of second digits and then plot the number we're logging. The highest logged number wins. My problem is that my code takes forever to run through all the second digits. Is there a faster way?

```
clear
clc

s=1000000;

for k = 618000:620000
    clear a
    a(1)=s;
    a(2)=k;
    n=3;
while a(n-1)>0
    a(n)=a(n-2)-a(n-1);
    n=n+1;    
end
a=a(:)

scatter(a(2),n-3,'b')
hold on

end
```

Any improvements on my code, specifically for plotting every digit faster (not the algebra - I know of Binet and all that. I want to stick as close to my method and I'll explore other methods myself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things slowing your code down, as annotated below:

```
s = 1000000;
for k = 618000:620000
    clear a % Excessive clearing, this is a slow function and not needed
    a(1)=s; % if you properly overwrite 'a' each iteration with 'a = [s, k]'
    a(2)=k;
    n=3;
    while a(n-1)>0
        a(n)=a(n-2)-a(n-1); % Growing array
        n=n+1;    
    end
    a=a(:) % This (:) operation is quick, but omitting the semi-colon causes
           % a relatively slow output to the console each iteration

    scatter(a(2),n-3,'b') % scattering every iteration is slow
    hold on               % 'hold' is slow, and only needed once per axis not each loop! 

end
```

Here is a much improved version which addresses most of my comments above:

```
s = 1000000;     % create some variables to make array indexing easier:
N = 2000;        %  - number of iterations
K0 = 618000;     %  - initial k
out = NaN(N, 1); %  - output, no growing arrays by pre-allocating here
for k = K0:(K0+N)
    a = [s, k];  % No 'clear', just create the array
    n = 2;       % The iteration could for this k
    while a(2) > 0
        temp = a(2);        % Temporarily put aside a(2)
        a(2) = a(1) - a(2); % Overwrite a(2) with the new difference
        a(1) = temp;        % Overwrite a(1) with the old a(2)
        n = n + 1;          % Increase iteration count
    end

    out(k-K0+1,1) = n;      % Track the iterations for this k    
end

scatter(K0:(K0+N), out, 'b') % Scatter all results at once, no need for 'hold'
```

The output of the revised script is created *very* quickly (< 1 sec)

[image: plot]

Comment: Wow this is fantastic. I initially used the Hold On because I was also using Draw Now but I got rid of that when the graph got too big. It will take me a while to understand what is going on here, even with your comments.

Comment: Just comment here if there's something specific which is unclear! Note you can also [profile your code](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html) to find bottlenecks... I didn't profile your code but I suspect the growing arrays and plotting in a loop were the slowest parts.